# Gradle: how to use the latest version of a plugin automatically

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have developed an internal plugin. The plugin has its own version.  I then use that plugin for a build process in a repository. 
If I change the version of the plugin, I have to update the build.gradle to spell our the new version.  I have about 100 of these repositories. 
Is there a way to specify in my build.gradle to use the latest version of the plugin that can be found in that location?
I could ran a batch file before gradle that find the latest, updates build.gradle with that number and then runs the build process but this is a big work around to a functionality that should be available.
See code below where I call the plugin that I change quite often:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "c:/git/_TEST/plug-in"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.myplugin.gradle', name: 'com.myplugin.mypluginbuild', version: '1.0'
    }
apply plugin: 'com.myplugin.mypluginbuild'
}
```

if I don't specify the version, it returns an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use dynamic versions: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules

Comment: No, they don't seem to work for community plugins:

[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Plugin [id: 'com.dorongold.task-tree', version: '1.3+'] was not found in any of the following sources:
10:25:24.593 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:25:24.593 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
10:25:24.593 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Plugin Repositories (**dynamic plugin versions are not supported**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who use **plugins{}** block, gradle7+ supports dynamic version, which includes **+** and **latest.release**.

```
plugins {
    id "your-plugin-id" version "1.0.+"
}
```

[dynamic version doc](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html#using-dynamic-versions-in-the-plugins-block)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible this way. See the [plugins {}](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.html) block and [plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) documentation.

- For core plugins you must not provide a version.
- For community plugins you have to provide a version.

Maybe [script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins) are way to go:

```
apply from: 'my_script_plugin.gradle'
```

Comment: Good suggestion but I am not able to use the Id statement. It fails because it can't find "com.myplugin.mypluginbuild" in Gradle Core or Gradle Central Repository. How do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this question.
The + specified in the version field will do the trick. It will enable gradle to use the latest plug-in automatically.
I.e:

```
dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.myplugin.gradle', name: 'com.myplugin.mypluginbuild', version: '1.+'
    }
```